# Dimension of the set of algebraic k-forms

Tags: combinatorics

> The number of distinct k-tuples where the indices $j_r$ are in strictly ascending order is the number of ways of choosing k distinct things from n things, so $\binom nk$.

How is this true? Surely after you have made your first choice there will be only the higher numbers remaining to choose from?

This comes from a discussion of the dimension of set of algebraic k-forms.

Comment: First choose the $k$ indices from $n$ indices which can be done in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways. Once you have chosen the indices, there is only one way to form the tuple, which is in the increasing order of indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space (or module over a ring), then $\wedge^kV$ is of dimension $\binom{n}{k}$ with basis elements $$e_{i_1}\wedge e_{i_2}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{i_k},\qquad 1\leq i_1<i_2<\dots<i_k\leq n.$$
Here $(e_i)$ is a basis of $V$. The condition on the indices *is* the choice of $k$ distinct elements out of $n$ distinct elements, with no repetition. The increasing order comes for free when you choose the indices, so the important part is the $<$, which reminds you not to choose the same index twice.